# Generate SignedData with Openssl console (with CRT)

Tags: console, openssl, sign

I'm really new to openssl and I need to generate a CMS Signed Data Message,I was given a xml file with some data in it, and I have a CRT and my private key.

How do I generate the CMS Signed Data using the xml, crt and key?? How do I write the command in the console

I've been looking in the documentation but I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

openssl cms -sign -in data.xml -nodetach -inkey private.key -signer cert.crt -out result.cms -outform PEM